# Admin on rest including in another react app "MuiThemeProvider.render()" error

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

i try use admin on rest in another app following the documentation about it, but i have an error when i try to use AppBar

```
MuiThemeProvider.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

const App = () => (
<Provider store={store}>
    <TranslationProvider /*messages={messages}*/>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>

            <MuiThemeProvider >
            <AppBar title="My Admin" />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} render={(routeProps) => <EventList resource="event" {...routeProps} />}/>
                    <Route exact path="/event" hasCreate render={(routeProps) => <EventList resource="event" {...routeProps} />} />
                    <Route exact path="/event/create" render={(routeProps) => <EventCreate resource="event" {...routeProps} />} />
                    <Route exact path="/event/:id" hasDelete render={(routeProps) => <EventEdit resource="event" {...routeProps} />} />
                </Switch>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </TranslationProvider>
</Provider>);
export default App;
```

anyone idea?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<MuiThemeProvider>` needs to have exactly one child so whatever you have inside needs to be wrapped.

eg

```
<MuiThemeProvider>
  <div>
    <AppBar title="My Admin" />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} render={(routeProps) => <EventList resource="event" {...routeProps} />}/>
      <Route exact path="/event" hasCreate render={(routeProps) => <EventList resource="event" {...routeProps} />} />
      <Route exact path="/event/create" render={(routeProps) => <EventCreate resource="event" {...routeProps} />} />
      <Route exact path="/event/:id" hasDelete render={(routeProps) => <EventEdit resource="event" {...routeProps} />} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```